# How to get the caller's number?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am creating one application,what I am trying is whenever user cut or disconnect call,one alert dialog should appear with caller's number,I followed [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/08/android-code-to-read-call-history-with.html) tutorial

```
 public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

         // get the phone number 
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" +incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(context, Disp_Alert_dialog.class); 
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.putExtra("Number", incomingNumber);

        context.startActivity(i);
        // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call



    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
            || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
        // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
    //    Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: so what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: the issue is after disconnect call i one alert dialog should appear..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

**To create a dialog box:**

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("This is the title")
.setMessage("This is the message")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // when yes is clicked
    }
 })
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // when no is clicked
    }
 })
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)//pic for the icon
 .show();
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Reusable call detector**
`

```
package com.gabesechan.android.reusable.receivers;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);                     
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                       
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                                               
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

`

**Functions**

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

}
```

Comment: can you tell all this with steps please??

Comment: and where can i create alert dialog...and see my edited question.. i followed your steps,,is there any mistakes

Comment: can you tell one more thing that..whenever i am getting call..my alert dialog is appearing..and what i want is alert dialog should appear only after disconnecting calls..

Comment: help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30724635/open-application-after-incoming-or-outgoing-call-diconnection